# how to calculate time complexity of for (int i = n - 1; i != 0; i /= 2) ?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

`for (int i = n - 1; i != 0; i /= 2) ++k;`

I am not able to understand how to calculate time complexity  for above.  I am unable to make out its behavior when n is negative. can anyone please help me to get there. I tried when n is positive.

```
Statement            Code      Time 
1a                  i=n-1       1 
1b                  i != 0    log2n+1
1c                  i = i/2   log2n
2                    ++k      log 2n
Total running time       3 log 2n+2
```

I got these values when i analyzed the code for n to be positive . but i failed to get when n is negative

Comment: How are you arriving at the values you've currently got? There seem to be some steps missing in your analysis.

Comment: It's the same: `O(log n)` in both cases.

Comment: When n is positive or negative, it is logn (base 2).

Comment: This is `0(n)` just because it's dividing by 2 doesn't make it base 2.

Comment: It doesn't matter if `n` is positive or negative.  In either case the `i /= 2` step divides the absolute value of `i` roughly in half and your iteration stops right after `abs(i) < 2`, since then the `i /= 2` step will cause `i` to be truncated to zero.

Comment: I say `0(log (n-1))` in base 2. To get this, the only operation you have to consider is that `i /= 2` and since `i` starts at `n-1` the complexity is `0(log (n-1))`. Opposite of this is to say that the value of `n-1` is `log(n-1) ** 2`

Comment: if n is 2 to the power of 16 then it will cycle for about 16 times, not 2 to the power of 16 times.

Comment: @AaronGolden Ahh i see it's essentially doing what binary search is doing. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Also, the base of the logarithm does not matter because [changing the base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base) only makes a constant factor difference, and constant factors are not taken into account for big-oh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This algorithm belongs to O(log(n)).  The longest running time occurs when `abs(n - 1)` is a power of 2, because in all other cases some of the `i /= 2` steps will cause `i` to take a value (whose absolute value is) slightly *less* than `abs(i / 2)`, due to truncation.

When `n - 1` is a power of 2, so `n - 1 == 2**a` for some `a`, then the loop will be executed `a + 1` times (once for `i` taking each of the values `1 = 2**0`, `2 = 2**1`, `4 = 2**2`, …, `n - 1 = 2**a`).  That is, the loop will be executed lg(n - 1) + 1 times.

I think some of your confusion stems from you trying to account for how many steps are taken inside the loop, but remember that these constant factors don't matter for the asymptotic runtime.  To prove that the runtimes is (say) O(log(n)) you need only show that the limit of "Actual runtime for n" / log(n), as n approaches infinity, is less than infinity.  If each iteration of the loop takes three steps or four steps, or a thousand steps, who cares?  As long as the gap between the actual runtime and log(n) is bound from above by *some* finite constant then it makes no difference.  For this same reason you don't need to worry about the base of the logarithm (2, or 10, or e, it's just a constant factor), or even whether the loop is executed lg(n - 1) times or lg(n - 1 +(-) m) +(-) p times for any constants m and p.

Comment: i am happy with your explanation @Aaron. but is O(f(n))is the only way to express time complexity? Instead of expressing in terms of order of some function, can we express time complexity in terms of some function, as I did in question.i.e.t(n)=3 log 2n+2. If yes, what is time complexity of the above question.As, I am just beginner to this concept of algorithm, sorry if my question is in appropriate..

Comment: Algorithmic complexity is almost always discussed in terms of bounding and/or dominating functions with constant factors and constant terms deemphasized.  In this particular case the precise number of operations will differ between architectures and between compilers, and even between options on the same compiler.  The context of the code can also play a role.  The constant factors are sometimes an important practical consideration, but at the end of the day, when software developers need to know how fast some code is in absolute terms they use profilers, not operation counting.